# Does a compound index without any equality fields (following the ESR rule) perform well in this situation?

Tags: mongodb, compound-index

I am fairly new to MongoDB and recently studied compound indexes. To be precise, the ESR rule. And I have a couple questions about using the $in operator.

According to the docs, $in acts as an equality operator when used alone. And it acts as a range operator when used with sort. I have to build a compound index for a filtering search where I have multiple attributes which I have to check for exact matches (can be multiple values) and also sort them according to the time when the document was created (so a lot of unique values). I did not know about the $in acting different in different scenarios before and assumed it is an equality operator every time. And hence created the following index:

`{field1: 1, field2: 1, field3: 1, created_at: -1}`

So my queries look kinda like this:

```
db.collection.find(
{
'field1': { $in: ['example1', 'example2'] },
'field2': { $in: ['example1', 'example2'] },
'field3': { $in: ['example1', 'example2'] }
}).sort({'created_at': -1})
```

Since not all fields are passed in by the user, in order to make my compound index cover the query, I put in all the possible values in the $in array in case a field is missing. My array size does not exceed 300.

The query given above, uses the index { `created_at: -1 }` instead of the compound index I created. I assume this is because using the compound index means the mongo will have to apply an in memory sort, which is undesirable if I am not wrong and hence the query planner goes ahead with the other index. Now my course of action to correct this would be to follow S => R and creating this compound index:

`{created_at: -1, field1: 1, field2: 1, field3: 1}`

This means all the fields which I am using for exact matches now become range operators. My question is, is there a better way to do this? Should I be using the $in operator here, instead of say, $or? And is this even a way to correctly do it in the first place? I am losing the E out of ESR and my concern is also that since `created_at` will have a lot of unique values, won’t traversing a compound index with `created_at` at the beginning take a long amount of time?

Few points to be kept in mind:

1. The collection contains over 3 million documents.
2. I will always have to sort the documents returned using the `created_at` attribute.

In a nutshell, I tried making this index

```
{field1: 1, field2: 1, field3: 1, created_at: -1}
```

But the compound index is not being used for my query. Now I am contemplating whether to create this index instead according to the above discussed problem. Or whether I am going in an incorrect direction altogether and if there is a better way to solve my problem.

```
{created_at: -1, field1: 1, field2: 1, field3: 1}
```